# Phonegap on WP7 does not load images

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm starting my first PhoneGap project and am developing using Visual Studio and Windows Phone 7, although I intend on ultimately deploying to iOS and Symbian as well.

However, I'm stuck at Step 1. I have added an image to the `www/images` folder, and put the following code:

```
<img src="images/login-btn.png" width="103" height="42" style="margin-left:90px;" />
```

And I get:

[image]

It works fine when I preview it in IE9, but I don't have a Mac to test it on iOS yet.

It's worth noting that the JS files and CSS have loaded fine, it's just any image (whether referenced in CSS or an `<img>` tag) always comes up broken.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My guess would be the `Build Action` of your image file is incorrect.

According to http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/48672055/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20Windows%20Phone%207#4Reviewtheprojectstructure section 4. You should be setting the `Build Action` of your images etc to `Content` which simply copies them into the output project when it is built. They are probably currently set to `Resource` or `None`.

To change the `Build Action` right click a file and choose properties to go to the properties window if you do not already have it open. It is probably then the first property. Just click and choose the correct one.

Comment: Hah, you know, I read that page about 50 times and every time I missed the last few words of Step B.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this to questions that I found while trying to find my answer to the same problem.  The JS framework I use adds a url query to each image when in a debugging mode (in order to force browsers to reload image, instead of using cached).  So, my image "image/background.jpg" would be accessed as "image/background.jpg?d=34342233".  But, when running on PhoneGAP for Windows Phone, it won't recognize the image, and thus it shows up as broken.  So, I had to turn off debugging for the framework I use, and suddenly the images showed up (still, don't forget to set the Build Action to "Content" as mentioned earlier).