# Using $.getJSON in a WP7 PhoneGap (Cordova) app (v1.5)

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I just have finished a PhoneGap app on iOS, now it's time to port it to WP7. One of the things the app must do is to read and parse a JSON file.

```
$.getJSON("xml-json/myfile.json",function(data){ 
 // do cool things
});
```

But when that line of code is executed, some error is thrown (there is no way to debug so I do not know what the error is), and the execution does not continue. Any idea what is wrong in that code? **That code works perfectly on the iOS version of PhoneGap.**

**This error is thrown in the Inmediate window: Log:"Wrapped XHR received Error from FileAPI :: [object Object]"**

Following suggestions, I tried to use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON. And the code works perfectly on the browser and on iOS, but not in WP7. Something simple like this does not work:

function onDeviceReady()
        {
            document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "Cordova is ready! version=" + window.device.cordova;
            console.log("onDeviceReady. You should see this message in Visual Studio's output window.");

```
        navigator.notification.alert("readingjson");

        $.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: "content2.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            context: document.body,
            success: function (a, b, c) {
                navigator.notification.alert("json readed");
            }
        });

        navigator.notification.alert('yeah');
    }
```

the "readingjson" alert is fired, "yeah" too, but the "json readed" one ner gets fired...

Thanks!

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug to Cordova developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not state which Cordova version you are using, however, there was a pretty major bug in v1.4 which meant that XHR requests failed. This was fixed in v1.5 - see this JIRA bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-208

If you are using 1.5 and still see problems, this is probably a new bug!

Comment: I told them it was a bug. I hope they solve it in the next version, or maybe it has been already solved (it was some months ago)

Answer (score 3):

Along with $.support.cors, you also need to set $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages to true.

Check the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html)

Comment: for Cordova 2.0, a tip: `function onDeviceReady() { $.support.cors = true;      $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You weren't very specific with the error etc. but before your JSON call try setting the following property:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Comment: not working :( How can I be more specific? PhoneGap does not throw any error or debug information, it simply freezes...

Answer (score 1):

Im using cordova 2.7.0 and I have the same problem.

It's not a bug, but here is a solution that worked for me:

1. Move your javascript code to seperate file and include it in your html to avoid annoying Visual Studio html inspector.
2. put "$.support.cors = true;" before ajax call. I include it on deviceready function.
3. do not put "$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;" as suggested on previous answer. In my case this line caused the application to hang.

My code looks like this:

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/content.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    $.support.cors = true; 
    getContents();
  }
</script>
```

contents.js

```
function getContents() {
    $.ajax({
url:"http://www.xxx.com/?getSomething",
    dataType:"json",
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Failed', function(){}, 'Info', 'OK');
    },
    success:function(data) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Success!', function(){}, 'Info', 'OK');
    }
});
}
```

Pardon my english.

Answer (score 0):

Try native ajax call this will resolve the issue.

Atleast it did for me.

~K

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't get debug information, are you using PhoneGap Build? Otherwise you should see logging from the app in the Output window from Visual Studio (ensure you are showing output from 'Debug').

If you are just using PhoneGap with Visual Studio, make sure that the JSON files are included in the project as content items and that your CordovaSourceDictionary.xml file is updated on build with those items.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902502/1441046