# Windows Phone 8 + Gif Preloader (Loading Animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'am developing a PhoneGap Application. and i have an ajax loader in the application, ie. whenever a ajax request is sent to server a loading animating .gif image appears. I have already developed iPhone and Android versions of the application.

But the problem is when i tried to deploy it in Windows Phone 8 the .gif animation doesn't work. Its not a CSS pre loader, its a simple .gif image. I checked WP8 Wikipedia page and there it clearly says WP8 supports .gif image.

Can somebody point out what's am doing wrong. if its something not possible then can someone please point out any different approaches?. Something simpler. (I don't want to add any 3rd party .js plugins in my app).

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried an animated png ?

Comment: is it .apng? nope.. i haven't tried it, will try it and let you know..!!

Comment: i searched quite some sites for generating .apng preloaders. but when clicking download the files were saved in (.png) format. is there really a .apng format ?? i also tried this tool too gif2apng.sourceforge.net

Comment: WP8 phonegap apps run on IE, as per wikipedia IE doesn't support apng http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG

Comment: oh .. I didnt knew that .. just for info here you can create .gif and animated PNG loader icons http://preloaders.net/

Answer (score 0):

Check the property of the gif image.

`Build Action` should be set to `Content`

[Phonegap on WP7 does not load images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902430/phonegap-on-wp7-does-not-load-images)